# Есть ли в ThreadPool локальная очередь задач для рабочих потоков?

Tags: c#

Решил освежить свои знания о работе пула потоков. В своих конспектах нашёл следующую схему работы пула потоков

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть судя по этой схеме алгоритм пула потоков следующий: у нас набор заготовленных потоков, есть глобальная очередь задач. Новая задача помещается в очередь, извлекается рабочим потоком, обрабатывается, поток возвращается в пул.

Но в чём загвоздка, я стал читать Рихтера и обнаружил, что потоки из пула работают совсем по другому. К всему выше написанному добавляется локальная очередь задач для каждого потока. И получается, что работа происходит по другому: сначала рабочий поток проверяет свою локальную очередь и локальные очереди других потоков, если в них нет задач, то только тогда идёт в главную очередь и достаёт задачу из неё, обрабатывает её и уходит в режим ожидания.

Схема с интернета

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cхема которую я взял с интернета похоже на мою.

Поясните, пожалуйста, как всё-таки пул потоков управляет своими потоками. Может Рихтер уже устарел, и всё давно не так))

UPD

В какой момент в локальной очереди потока будет добавлена задача? У Рихтера ничего не сказано про это не сказано

Comment: Хм, в последние годы мне не попадалось новых статей об этом, а раньше про это много писали. Что интересно, ни здесь: [ThreadPool Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-8.0), ни здесь: [The managed thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool) нет упоминания work-stealing. В описании [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-7.0#Stealing) есть раздел про это. Как ввели эту функциональность в .NET FW 4, так и не отменяли.

Comment: Ну то есть у Рихтера правильно всё написано? Просто меня это так смутило, что я решил задать вопрос))

Comment: [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=net-7.0#remarks) - здесь тоже упомянуто steal work. / Да, у Рихтера всё правильно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, поправлю свои конспекты. Я просто стал гуглить и не нашёл информацию о локальных очередях потоков

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я обновил вопрос, может быть подскажете))

Comment: [The global queue vs. local queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-7.0#the-global-queue-vs-local-queues). Язык можно переключить на русский в левом нижнем углу.

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть. В локальную очередь помещаются **вложенные** или **дочерние задачи**. То есть те, которые были созданы внутри основной задачи, которая обрабатывается потоком пула.

Советую прочитать эту статью, тут достаточно подробно подымается тема Пула потоков и Планировщика задач (Task Scheduler) и того, каким образом организована работа очередей (глобальной и локальной): https://csharpcooking.github.io/2022/02/27/Task-Scheduler.html

А так же вот эта: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-8.0#Queues

И еще одна статья: https://medium.com/net-under-the-hood/internal-mechanisms-of-tasks-in-net-ef461956d4a7

Цитата из статьи выше (medium.com):

> "Дефолтный пул потоков .NET содержит одну глобальную очередь FIFO и
> локальные очереди (по одной для каждого потока пула) LIFO."